# Internet Explorer stuck saving images as BMP format instead of JPEG

Tags: windows, images, internet-explorer, jpeg, bmp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE 8 likes to save photos as BMP when the photo is JPG.  How to solve this?](https://superuser.com/questions/61623/ie-8-likes-to-save-photos-as-bmp-when-the-photo-is-jpg-how-to-solve-this)

I'm using Internet Explorer 8 on Vista and when I save a picture using "Save as..." it will only save as a bitmap and not as a jpeg.

I have cleared my cache etc. What could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have an example URL?

Comment: Sounds like a dupe. http://superuser.com/questions/61623/ie-8-likes-to-save-photos-as-bmp-when-the-photo-is-jpg-how-to-solve-this

Answer (score -1):

My bet is the image format is actually really BMP or something non-jpeg.

Take a look at my [demo page here](http://74er.net/labs/su-logo.html), open it in IE and try to save the images, you will get what I mean.

Comment: Answer the older question instead: http://superuser.com/questions/61623/ie-8-likes-to-save-photos-as-bmp-when-the-photo-is-jpg-how-to-solve-this